# np.argsort which excludes zero values

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have an array `[0.2,0,0,0,0.3,0,0,0,0.4]`. I'm using `np.argsort` to sort values and get that indexes.

So, for my example, it will be something like `[1,5,9,2,3,4,6...]`. However, I would like to get array of indexes only for **non zero values**.

In my example only `[1,5,9]`.

How do I implement it in python with `pandas` and `numpy`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Using `np.nonzero` and indexing trick

```
def sparse_argsort(arr):
    indices = np.nonzero(arr)[0]
    return indices[np.argsort(arr[indices])]

sparse_argsort(a)

array([0, 4, 8])
```

one liner:

```
(lambda a: (lambda a_, i_: i_[np.argsort(a_[i_])])(a,np.nonzero(a)[0]))(a)

array([0, 4, 8])
```

Answer (score 5):

one line numpy

```
np.where(a != 0, a, np.nan).argsort()[:(a != 0).sum()]
```

same logic, two lines, more efficient

```
nz = a != 0
np.where(nz, a, np.nan).argsort()[:nz.sum()]

array([0, 4, 8])
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try:

```
pd.Series([0.2,0,0,0,0.3,0,0,0,0.4]).sort_values()[lambda x: x != 0].index.values
# array([0, 4, 8])
```

Or use `numpy`:

```
ind = arr.argsort()
ind[arr[ind] != 0]

# array([0, 4, 8])
```

Comment: The "lambda as a filter" to do a one liner is neat!

Answer (score 1):

You can cheat a bit with `numpy.where`, since it defaults to `condition.nonzero()` anyway.  Use `numpy.in1d` to build a mask.

```
x=[0.2,0,0,0,0.3,0,0,0,0.4]

np.argsort(x)[np.in1d(np.argsort(x),np.where(x),1)]

Out[35]: array([0, 4, 8], dtype=int32)
```